# How to create view with close button above the corner?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

How do you usually create views with button in top-left corner to create something like view presented at the picture?

Do I have to simply place button with image over the corner? Or there are some best pratices? :) Just wondering.

[image: View with close button in the corner]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will place the offset of the button like -10 *(if your button is around 30x30)* for X and Y.

In your example, that looks like [`Pro Switcher`](https://github.com/rpetrich/ProSwitcher), just look at the source there and see how he has done it.

Answer (score 2):

Check the write up by Matt Gemmell on the UI design of his "Favorites" app. He discusses those "close" buttons specifically.

[Favorites UI design](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/10/29/favorites-ui-design)

Answer (score 0):

create button in parent vie and set its frame close to your subview

```
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(aMethod:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 80, 30, 30);
[self.view addSubview:button];
```