# How to implement "X" close button for Modal View Form Sheet

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, modalviewcontroller

I understand that there are already questions out there asking the same thing however, I still had no luck in implementing an "X" button in the corner of a Form Sheet Modal View.

A perfect example of what I am trying to implement can be seen in the screenshot [**HERE**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b2e0fxjo6txnctt/IMG_0032.PNG).

In a vain attempt, I have tried implementing a UIButton In the viewDidLoad of the modal view's View Controller class with a frame of `CGRectMake(-10, -10, 20, 20)` but as expected, the button doesn't "Hover" at the top left corner of the modal view as intended.

**Some of the questions that I've stumbled upon:**

- [How to create view with close button above the corner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009110/how-to-create-view-with-close-button-above-the-corner) (Correct answer leads to a github project and I couldn't find the relevant codes. 2nd answer doesn't talk about the implementation of an "X" button in the corner at all.)
- [Add close button to UIModalPresentationPageSheet corner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976809/add-close-button-to-uimodalpresentationpagesheet-corner) (Answer suggest a left bar button item. Which is a great alternative but isn't what the main intention of our questions are.)
- [how to add close button to modal view corner which is presented in UIModalPresentationPageSheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983731/how-to-add-close-button-to-modal-view-corner-which-is-presented-in-uimodalpresen) (Answer don't work and I don't understand why. I don't understand the logic of the answer either.)

I have already got "Tap outside modal view to dismiss" working, and now I need to had that little close button at the top for HCI sake.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with trying to figure out how to dismiss a sheet view. From what I've read, a sheet must be dismissed by the view that displayed it.  A view controller has a reference to the presenting view, so the sheet view requests its parent to dismiss the sheet (self).

After implementing with a button, I found info about cancelOperation which captures esc or 'command-.' and both work.

I'm not sure if this is correct practice but it is working (so far) for me.

```
class PopupSheet : NSViewController {
    // dismiss if ok button is clicked
    @IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: Any?) {
        self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(self)
    }
    // dismiss if esc or command-. is pressed
    override func cancelOperation(_ sender: Any?) {
        self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(self)
    }
}
```